# spoj.com prime generator time limit exceeded

Tags: c

Getting time limit exceeded on submitting answer.  I am also facing same problem with 2-3 more questions that I have submitted on spoj.com.

http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

> Peter wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given numbers!
>
> Input
>
> The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.
>
> Output
>
> For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.
>
> Example
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 2
> 1 10
> 3 5
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 7
>
> 3
> 5
> ```
>
> Warning: large Input/Output data, be careful with certain languages (though most should be OK if the algorithm is well designed)

Here is my code in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t,i,k,count;
    long long int j=0,m=0,n=0;

    scanf("%d",&t);

    for(i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld%lld",&m,&n);

        for(j=m;j<=n;j++)
        {
            count=0;
            for(k=1;k<=j/2;k++)
            {
                if(j%k==0)
                    count++;
                if(count>1)
                    break;
            }

            if(count==1)
                printf("%lld\n",j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the sieve of Eratosthenes and combining that with a binary search? Or hard coding the primes?

Comment: brute force won't work.You might want to google sieve of eratosthenes.

Comment: please, for readability/understandability, consistently indent the code.  Suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is O((m-n)*n) which of course won't run within the allocated time limit. Let's go over your code:

```
count=0;
for(k=1;k<=j/2;k++)
{
if(j%k==0)
count++;
if(count>1)
break;
}
if(count==1)
printf("%lld\n",j);
```

*Micro optimization*: Why do you need a counter? You could get away with a bool.

*Optimization*: Why are you testing primes `j/2`? If `j` has a divisor greater than 1 than it's guaranteed that `j` has a divisor that's at most `sqrt(j)`.

*Micro Optimization*: Don't consider even numbers at all, except for 2.

```
bool prime = j==2 || j%2==1 ;
for(k=2;prime && k*k<=j;k++)
{
if(j%k==0) prime = false;
}
}
if(prime) printf("%lld\n",j);
```

Now this is O((m-n)*sqrt(n)) which is a lot faster.

I suppose this won't make the limit. You could extend the second micro-optimization to skip numbers divisible by 3 very easy.

*Optimization*: If this is still not enough then you have to do a pseudo-primality test. One test that's very easy to implement in O(log(n)) is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test. With this the complexity is down to O((m-n)*log(n)) which should be run in the available time limit.